# Fitting a curve

Tags: plotting, fitting, interpolation

I want to find the curve that would fit the following data:

```
A = ListPlot[{{0, 1.1328905824168953`}, {10, 
0.20797321693370777`}, {20, 1.2848740785327655`}, {30, 
0.6179718175299685`}, {40, 0.8831124565751295`}, {50, 
1.0316642663320958`}, {60, 0.20797321328616594`}, {70, 
1.3193300722085401`}, {80, 0.21474524365107694`}, {90, 
0.9831556560390069`}, {100, 0.9302672089098535`}, {110, 
0.21863622973937585`}, {120, 1.3067816501657834`}, {130, 
0.20797320969885633`}, {140, 1.0852302056303988`}, {150, 
0.8316695593967324`}, {160, 0.6179718031118292`}, {170, 
1.250770419141855`}, {180, 0.08204490638155054`}, {190, 
1.1830638403732725`}, {200, 0.7300414170334597`}, {210, 
0.7506872445971947`}, {220, 1.1651831339460743`}, {230, 
0.20797320422323495`}, {240, 1.2642742988843874`}, {250, 
0.6179718133676338`}, {260, 0.8503877128256928`}, {270, 
1.0657597861903736`}, {280, 0.20797320796101057`}, {290, 
1.3128379911769938`}, {300, 0.2173060329530538`}, {310, 
0.9494434167430037`}, {320, 0.9637801491491741`}, {330, 
0.2162627849720886`}, {340, 1.3162500045015266`}, {350, 
0.207973201936994`}, {360, 1.0512301621752311`}}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium]}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 370}, {0, 1.5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want the points be also vesible in the curve that approximates this data. Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CurveFitting.html)?

Comment: Guessing at the function that describes this data isn't really a *Mathematica* question ... (Well, there is `FindFormula`)  It is also not a question that can be answered without knowing where the data came from.  How to fit curves in general in Mathematica is described in detail in the documentation (see Jason's link).  You should read that, and then ask a specific question about where exactly you had difficulties.

Comment: If you just want to have a curve that goes through your data points and looks decent, without having an analytic form for the fit, then you could just use something like `ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red,
 InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point@dta}]` which returns [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FpCAN.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your data looks it best visualized in polar form.

```
data = 
  {{0, 1.13289}, {10, 0.207973}, {20, 1.28487}, 
  {30, 0.617972}, {40, 0.883112}, {50, 1.03166}, 
  {60, 0.207973}, {70, 1.31933}, {80, 0.214745}, 
  {90, 0.983156}, {100, 0.930267}, {110, 0.218636}, 
  {120, 1.30678}, {130, 0.207973}, {140, 1.08523}, 
  {150, 0.83167}, {160, 0.617972}, {170, 1.25077}, 
  {180, 0.0820449}, {190, 1.18306}, {200, 0.730041}, 
  {210, 0.750687}, {220, 1.16518}, {230, 0.207973}, 
  {240, 1.26427}, {250, 0.617972}, {260, 0.850388}, 
  {270, 1.06576}, {280, 0.207973}, {290, 1.31284}, 
  {300, 0.217306}, {310, 0.949443}, {320, 0.96378}, 
  {330, 0.216263}, {340, 1.31625}, {350, 0.207973}, 
  {360, 1.05123}};
```

Since the 1st element of each pair looks like it was measured in degrees, the data must be transformed so the 1st element is in radians.

```
dataInRad = {N[#[[1]] Degree], #1[[2]]} & /@ data;
```

This will make a smoothed polar plot of your data.

```
smooth = 
  ListPolarPlot[dataInRad, 
    Joined -> True, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
    PolarAxes -> True, 
    PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic},
    PolarGridLines -> True];
```

This will make a polar plot of the raw data points.

```
points = ListPolarPlot[dataInRad, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}];
```

And this will display the two plots together.

```
Show[smooth, points]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

**Comment**

Are you looking for something like this?

```
F = ListInterpolation[data[[All, 2]], {{0, 350}}]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 350}, PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True]
```

[image]